# Installing jboss-as-7.1.1.Final as a Windows Service using Apache Commons Daemon (prunsrv.exe)

Tags: java, windows, jboss, procrun

How can I configure JBoss 7 (specifically jboss-as-7.1.1.Final) as a windows service using Apache Commons Daemon (prunsrv.exe)?

Specifically, I don't know the correct JBoss options for either prunsrv.exe, or for the prunmgr.exe GUI.

If you have the prunsrv.exe parameters to install the standalone server as a windows service (eg. a batch file that creates a JBoss 7 windows service) that would be perfect.  Alternatively, your settings from prunmgr GUI would be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are instruction on running [ProcRun](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) available, in case you need more details on it.  When I have used prunsrv I have used a Service Creation line like the following:

```
prunsrv.exe install JBossEAP6 --DisplayName="JBoss EAP 6" --Description "JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6" --LogLevel=INFO --LogPath="C:\Program Files\EAP-6.1.1\jboss-eap-6.1\standalone\log" --LogPrefix=service --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto --StartMode=exe --StartImage=cmd.exe --StartPath="C:\Program Files\EAP-6.1.1\jboss-eap-6.1\bin" ++StartParams="/c \"set NOPAUSE=Y ^&^& run.bat\"" --StopMode=exe --StopImage=cmd.exe --StopPath="C:\Program Files\EAP-6.1.1\jboss-eap-6.1\bin"  ++StopParams="/c jboss-cli.bat --controller=localhost:9999 --connect --command=:shutdown"
```

This does expect that you have JBoss installed in windows at: C:\Program Files\EAP-6.1.1\jboss-eap-6.1

You need to make sure your run.bat has the right settings, which I have set up to have the following:

```
for /D %%i in ("C:\Program Files\EAP-6.1.1\jboss-eap-6.1\standalone\tmp\vfs\*")
do RD /S /Q "%%i"
cd %JBOSS_HOME%\bin\
standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement <localIP>
```

This gets me a working Windows service that also cleans up after itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Descargamos "commons-daemon-1.0.15-bin-windows.zip", e.g. desde
   http://mirrors.advancedhosters.com/apache/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/
2. Descomprimimos en el directorio del Jboss %JBOSS_HOME%\bin
3. En el directorio bin sacamos un respaldo de run.bat y cambiamos el rub.bat por lo siguiente:

%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\standalone.bat -c saap.xml -b 0.0.0.0

1. Luego para crear el servicio ejecutamos lo siguiente de acuerdo a
   nuestra configuración de servidor.

   .\prunsrv.exe install Saap --DisplayName="Saap" --Description "Sistema de Gestión de Agua Potable" --LogLevel=INFO --LogPath="D:\server\jboss-as-7.1.1\standalone\log" --LogPrefix=service --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto --StartMode=exe --StartImage=cmd.exe --StartPath="D:\server\jboss-as-7.1.1\bin" ++StartParams="/c \"set NOPAUSE=Y ^&^& run.bat\"" --StopMode=exe --StopImage=cmd.exe --StopPath="D:\server\jboss-as-7.1.1\bin"  ++StopParams="/c jboss-cli.bat --connect command=:shutdown"
2. Y listo al reiniciar ya podemos visualizar nuestro servidor
   desplegado

Comment: This is an english site, thus kindly translate your answer into english